# Proof involving multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus

Let the three-variable function f be differentiable and satisfy $$f(t\vec{x})) = t^{p}f(\vec{x}) $$ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $ and $ t \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Prove that $$ \vec{x} \cdot \nabla{f(\vec{x})} = pf(\vec{x})$$ for all $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

I tried using a substitution $\vec{v} = t\vec{x}$ and then differentiating both sides of the function with respect to t to get $$\frac{d}{dt}f(\vec{v}) = pt^{p-1}f(\vec{x}) $$ Then the left side by the chain rule.. 
$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}\frac{dv_i}{dt}  =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}x_i =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{d x_i}{d v_j}x_j= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{1}{t}x_i=\frac{1}{t}\nabla f\cdot \vec{x}$$
Now plugging this back in doesn't quite give the right expression:
$$ \nabla f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{x} = p\cdot t^pf(\vec{x})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your partial differentation by $t$ was not executed correctly.

By the chain rule, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t\overrightarrow{x})$ is the fourth entry of the $1$-by-$4$ matrix $$D(f\circ g)(\overrightarrow{x},t)=\nabla f(t\overrightarrow{x})Dg(\overrightarrow{x},t)$$ where $g(\overrightarrow{x},t):=t\overrightarrow{x}$. Elementary computation shows that the rightmost column of $Dg(\overrightarrow{x},t)$ is $(x,y,z)^{T}$.  Thus, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t\overrightarrow{x})=\nabla f(t\overrightarrow{x})\cdot \overrightarrow{x}$$ and hence, $$\nabla f(\overrightarrow{x})\cdot \overrightarrow{x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=1}f(t\overrightarrow{x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=1}(t^{p}f(\overrightarrow{x}))|_{t=1}=(pt^{p-1}f(\overrightarrow{x}))|_{t=1}=pf(\overrightarrow{x})$$

This completes the proof.  The problem that you had was that you shouldn't use the power rule when computing the derivative of $f(v)$ with respect to $t$.